# CSS Flexbox / Fixing footer on bottom of the page in all cases

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm getting issue to get my footer at bottom of page in all cases, or it's disappearing when scrolling up or down, or it's just showing at the top of the page...
Tried to find out on here but impossible for me to get it..

I do apologize if this post is a duplicate from an existing one..

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  height: 25px;
  order: 4;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <span>Text of my footer</span>
</footer>
```

Not sure if Grid might help on such situation and make life easier?

And thank you for any answer! :)
Rgds,
Erick

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed` and set `bottom: 0px`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  height: 25px;
  order: 4;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <span>Text of my footer</span>
</footer>
```

You might need to add `width: 100%`

Comment: That's cool! Thanks, is this the best way to handle such thing? I still have an issue, the footer is not spreading in the entiere height, just on 1/5.. how can I do for the footer to show on 100% of height of the screen?

Comment: width: 100% answers! :D

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: fixed;` and `bottom: 0;`.

`position` `fixed` set the position to stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  height: 25px;
  order: 4;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <span>Text of my footer</span>
</footer>
```

---

- [Documentation of position: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [Documentation of position: W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)